# Given $X$ a normal topological space $J \subset X,$ $J \simeq D ^2$. Prove that $J$ is a retract of $X$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given $X$ a normal topological space $J \subset X,$ $J \simeq D ^2$. Prove that $J$ is a retract of $X$.

Not really sure how to approach this one. I guess I have to somehow use Urysohn's lemma, but I'm not sure exactly how. Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: $D^2$ is a closed disk? You need Tietze's theorem rather than Urysohn.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use $[0,1]^2$, as it's homeomorphic to $D^2$, say via a homeorphism $h: D^2 \rightarrow [0,1]^2$. If $j$ is the homeomorphism from $J$ to $D^2$, then $h \circ j$ is a map from $J$ (which is a closed subspace of the normal space $X$) onto $[0,1]^2$. Call the two projections onto the factors $[0,1]$ of this map $h_1$ and $h_2$. Extend these maps $h_1$ and $h_2$ to $X$ (call the extensions $\overline{h_1}$ and $\overline{h}_2$, say) by [Tietze's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem).

Then $j^{-1} \circ h^{-1} \circ (\overline{h_1} \times \overline{h_2})$ is the required retraction.